# How can I test my vim plugin?

Tags: macos, vim, clojure

Hi guys : I recently (accidentally) removed all folders/files from my .vim folder in mac os x (home directory).

I am trying to add in the Clojure Vim plugin (VimClojure) - its simply a folder which you are supposed to "drop into .vim/plugins".

I have added it, but I don't see any changes to the syntax highlighting when I launch vim.  I'm not sure wether vim "sees" the plugin or not.

I'm on OS X .

Any ideas on how to debug the plugin ? In particular

1) How does VIM look for plugins ?
2) Are there files which need to be in $HOME/.vim/ ?
3) Is it sufficient to simply dump the unzip a new plugin file into $HOME/.vim/plugins when installing a standard vim plugin ?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, what you ask for is not «testing your vim plugin». When I saw the title I thought you have written your own plugin and is looking for a way to add some tests (I write lots of functional tests for my plugins and was preparing to tell you how I run them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About debugging: in order to see whether vim has loaded your plugin you can use `:scriptnames` and also `breakadd file /path/to/your/plugin` (or `breakadd file *your_plugin_name.vim`: I never used absolute paths so I do not know what breakadd will do in this case). Other questions:

1. Described in `:h initialization`, precisely `:h load-plugins`.
2. Vim does not need any files at all (except vim executable, used shared libraries, dynamic linker and the kernel of course).
3. Follow installation instructions. Normally plugins are either extracted to `~/.vim` or distributed as a singe file that should go to either `~/.vim/plugin` (no `s`!), `~/.vim/colors`, `~/.vim/ftplugin` or such. I guess you should try to extract it to `~/.vim/plugin`, but if archive contains some special directories like `plugin/`, `ftplugin/`, `colors/`, `after/` (see `/usr/share/vim/vim73` for a list) it is likely that it should go to `~/.vim`. Also consider using [vim-addon-manager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905), if plugin was posted on vim.org VAM is likely to be able to install it.

Answer (score 2):

A few points.

1. How does vim look for plugins?  See `:help startup` so see where and when vim looks for  files to load.
2. Not really.  Anything there is just personal customization.  Vim will run fine without a .vim folder.
3. That all depends on the plugin.  It sounds to me like the VimClojure plugin may be a little misleading.  Do you have a link to the source you are using?

In any case, the first step I always take when attempting to debug a script is check the output of `:scriptnames`.  This command will show you what scripts vim has loaded for the current session.  If you see none of the files shipped with VimClojure, you probably made a mistake during the installation.

Another tip is that you really should look in to using a plugin manager such as [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) or [vim-addon-manager](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager), or at least the `runtimepath` manager [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen).  This seems to be the way of the future for vim configuration these days and it makes installing and managing plugins much easier.  They also help to keep your .vim folder clean and organized.

Comment: Two answers at almost the same time with very similar contents :)

Comment: @ZyX It's almost like we know what we're talking about :D

Answer (score 1):

The VimClojure directory should either be extraction *on top of* your `.vim` folder, or in a `bundle` folder if your using something like [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) (which you should!). If you're starting from scratch, consider starting with [vimclojure-easy](https://github.com/daveray/vimclojure-easy) (not to toot my own horn) which is a basic, full install of VimClojure with instructions.